# SVN Checkout 2 different branches into same parent folder

Tags: svn

I have following structure in project:

```
http://svn/platform/<version>
http://svn/product/<version>
```

I cannot simply run checkout to svn/, since it get me all versions.
What I want to achieve - checkout to folder, where will be "platform" and "product" subfolders with only one needed version.

I cannot run something like this:

```
svn co http://svn/platform/1.0/ https://svn/product/1.0/
```

Since it will fail to create second folder 1.0 in same folder, and this not, what I want to achieve.

I am using "svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)"

Comment: Why not `cd` into "platform", and then `svn co http://svn/platform/1.0/ .`, then `cd` into "product" and `svn co https://svn/product/1.0/ .`?

Comment: It will create 2 different folders, with separate .svn inside. I need one root .svn folder.

Comment: My guess is that isn't possible, since you're checking out from two different branches.  I'd think that the SVN metadata would clobber itself if you try to bring both paths into the same local root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researched this a bit by myself. Looks like - in svn there are no way :(